Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly
After updating to WordPress 6.7, I’m receiving the following PHP notice on my website. How can I resolve this issue?
Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly. Translation loading for the blahblah domain was triggered too early. This is usually an indicator for some code in the plugin or theme running too early. Translations should be loaded at the init action or later. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 6.7.0.) in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 6114


See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/10/21/i18n-improvements-6-7/

Supplementary, this error is thrown in line 6114 of wp-includes/functions.php. I would like to surpress it for the time being in local and staging.  So it's possible to add 6114-6116  if (! str_contains($message, '_load_textdomain_just_in_time') ) {trigger_error($message, $error_level);} but this is hacking core (oo-err). I'd like to use the hook add_filter( 'wp_trigger_error_run','suppress_text_domain_error',999, 2 ); function suppress_text_domain_error( $message, $error_level) {...} but this doesn't work.

There is discussion on WP for reverting the changes in 6.7 because of this causing to much noise in the debug logs. Also there was this suggested work around to make then doing_it_wrong shut up - didn't test to see if it works.

@Ale - I can confirm that workaround plugin works.

If You're a Website Owner

Try updating your themes and plugins, as the issue may already have been resolved by the developers.
If the problem persists, report the issue to the plugin or theme authors so they can address it in a future update.
To identify the plugin or theme causing the error, look for the text domain mentioned in the error message. For example, in the following message, blahblah is the text domain:

Translation loading for the blahblah domain.
If You're a Plugin / Theme Author
Check your textdomain registration code and make sure the function is set to init hook or later. By textdomain registration code I mean the load_textdomain, load_plugin_textdomain, or load_theme_textdomain functions.
For example the following code is wrong and should get fixed.
add_action('plugins_loaded', function()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain('your-textdomain', false, '/path/to/your/plugin/languages/');
});

The following code is the correct one:
add_action('init', function()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain('your-textdomain', false, '/path/to/your/plugin/languages/');
});

Use of the get_plugin_data Function
If you are using the get_plugin_data function before the WordPress init hook, you must pass false as the third parameter or adjust your code logic to ensure it runs after the init hook.
For more information you can check the https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/10/21/i18n-improvements-6-7/ URL.

I get this message when I use the function “get_plugin_data” with a corresponding include on “wp-admin/includes/plugin.php”. But I need this for administration and upgrade purposes.

@Regnalf, open your own question if you need help.

Correct code is missing semicolon after closing load_plugin_textdomain bracket

@neilgee Thanks for your report. It's added.

Lots of plugins are seeing this error NOT caused by incorrect text domain loading, but by other WordPress functions.
My plugin was using 'get_plugin_data' and getting was this error.  I am still seeing it for other WP functions.
I replaced 'get_plugin_data' with
$plugin_data = get_file_data(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/bbpress/bbpress.php', array('Version' => 'Version'), false);

as a workaround.
But major plugins such as woocommerce (8 million installations)and really simple security (4 million installations) are seeing issues, and I gather it has been raised for a WP fix, rather than forcing plugin authors to work round it.
https://developer.woocommerce.com/2024/11/11/developer-advisory-translation-loading-changes-in-wordpress-6-7/

You can still use get_plugin_data, just with the third parameter set to false. Seee https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/10/21/i18n-improvements-6-7/

I manage a lot of websites.
Basically, after Wordpres 6.7 update, a few websites which had 'WP_DEBUG' as true, started to show errors about _load_textdomain_just_in_time.
It is happening with a lot of plugins.

How do I fix it

I was able to fix it by changing my wp-config.php line for WP_DEBUG was set to false, for example:  define('WP_DEBUG', false);

@Benson you have just hide error, Actually error is not solved.

Yes, good point, @Niranjan Gondaliya the error is not resolved, but hidden. However, for live sites, with some templates, the error will kill the website.  Hiding the error is the best solution on live sites. As Niranjan Gondaliya infers, it's best to resolve this error by showing it on a development version of your site to fully resolve this error.

Yes right @Benson

What worked for me in similar situation:

Go to File Editor, rename wp-content/plugins folder to whatever
This allowed me to log in at /wp-admin
Go to updates and reinstall wordpress even if it is most recent
Go to plugins page, it will show you plugins are missing files 
Then go back to file editor, rename folder back to "plugins"
Update all plugins

error should disappear
